# Getting Date/Time range month wise for last 6 months in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, jodatime

I need to design a report for Sales. The requirement is to get the last 6 months of Sales record month-wise and the report will get trigger on 1st day of every month containing data for the last six months. So for example - If the report has to trigger on 1 April 2020 at 10:00 AM then I want end date for the report as - 31 March 2020 23:59:59 and start date as 1 October 2019 00:00:00. And in between these start and end dates I want range of dates months wise to get data from DB for that month. For example -

```
For March - Start Date -- 2020-03-01 00:00:00 End Date -- 2020-03-31 23:59:59
For Feb- Start Date -- 2020-02-01 00:00:00 End Date -- 2020-02-29 23:59:59
```

and so on...
Desired date format is - yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I am planning to use LocalDateTime for this but not able to figure out how to actually achieve this.
My code is below -

```
LocalDateTime endDate = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime startDate = endDate.minusMonths(6);
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
for (LocalDateTime date = endDate; date.isAfter(startDate); date = date.minusMonths(1)) {
            System.out.println(date.format(dateFormatter3));
        }
```

This is my basic approach to this problem. I am planning to use a for loop so that I can get start date and end date for every month and query the data from DB. Please help me how can I split the date/time month-wise and use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for your purposes, I think:

```
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);

    ArrayList<LocalDateTime> dateTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(startDate.minusMonths(i), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
        dateTimes.add(start);

        LocalDateTime end = start.plusMonths(1).minusSeconds(1);
        dateTimes.add(end);
    }

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    for(LocalDateTime value : dateTimes) {
        System.out.println(value.format(dateFormatter3));
    }
```

The ArrayList will contain the start and end date/times for the previous 6 months. From there, you just need to go through the loop and grab the pairs out for your queries. Something like:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < dateTimes.size(); i += 2) {
        LocalDateTime start = dateTimes.get(i);
        LocalDateTime end = dateTimes.get(i + 1);
        //Pass them off to the query
    }
```

You could also just pass the found values from the first loop directly in the query without storing them in the ArrayList. Either approach should be fine.

Comment: Instead of `LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), 1)`, use `LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1)`, or `YearMonth.now().atDay(1)`, and get rid of `now`. --- Instead of `LocalTime.of(0, 0)`, use `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT`.

Comment: @Andreas Fair enough, mate.